# How can I align the corresponding options (vertically) in the exam class?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exam

I am trying to prepare a question paper for a test, and I'd like the choices of the multiple choice questions to be aligned, that is, I'd like all the A's, B's, C's and D's to be aligned just like in an array or table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{exam}

\begin{document}
\section*{Multiple Choice Questions}

\begin{questions}

    \question   This is question number one with four options.

    \begin{oneparchoices}
        \choice     64
        \choice     40
        \choice     20
        \choice     32
    \end{oneparchoices}
\question   This is question number two with four (lengthier) options

\begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice     option 1
    \choice     option 2
    \choice     option 3
    \choice     option 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: Aligning choices exam documentclass]

I understand that this can be achieved using the `tabular` or any similar environment, but I'd like to know whether there is any easy way of achieving this within the `oneparchoices` environment.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `tasks` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
    counter-format={tsk[A].}, 
    label-align=left,
    item-indent={20pt}, 
    column-sep={4pt},
    label-width={16pt},
    }

\begin{document}
\section*{Multiple Choice Questions}

\begin{questions}
\question   This is question number one with four options.
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task     64
        \task     40
        \task     20        
        \task     32
    \end{tasks}

\question   This is question number two with four (lengthier) options
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task   option 1
        \task   option 2
        \task   option 3
        \task   option 4
    \end{tasks}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]